# How to create roll-up summary on currency field in multi-currency organizations?

Tags: roll-up-summary, multi-currency

I have Opportunity as master and OppDetail__c as detail (Opportunity__c field as Master-Detail(Opportunity)). I created two fields on OppDetail__c - first of type Currency and second of type Number. When I attempt to create roll-up summary field in Opportunity with 'Summarized Object' as OppDetail__c, 'Field to Aggregate' combobox has only one option - Number.

How to create roll-up summary on currency field in multi-currency organizations?

EDIT1:

Found [Roll-up Summary field is still calculating](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000041377) saying

> If you have this (advanced currency management) feature enabled (you can check by going to Setup | Company Profile | Manage Currencies), you cannot create roll-up summary fields that calculate currency on the opportunity object.

So, no way right now to create it in straightforward way (without code)?

Comment: That's right no way to do it easily, but I invite you to vote for the idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMq

Comment: @CloudNinja, you killed me with your comment :-( However, now I know for 100% that this is not possible. Please, post it as answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, no way to do it easily, but I invite you to vote for the idea [success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMq](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMq)

PS: Sorry for killing your day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid application in the Appexchange which covers this salesforce gap without development needed.

This article explain how:
https://axy7.com/solving-rollup-summary-for-multi-currency-in-salesforce/

PS: no intention to publicity, but sharing an existing option to the idea posted before